# DLL Redirection for wsock32

Tags: c++, windows, firefox, dll

I am trying to redirect a call to gethostbyname in wsock32 DLL. I found a [tutorial](http://sourcesecure.net/2011/03/dll-redirection-tutorial/) that exactly performs this operation.

However, the steps illustrated here does not seem to work. If I open the firefox browser (after following all steps), an error stating "Couldn't load XPCOM" pops up. I failed trying to search for solutions that rectify this error. (The error occurs only when I copy the newly created wsock32.dll file in the firefox directory, as per the tutorial).
I am using Windows 7 with the latest firefox version, and Visual Studio 2015.

I am new to this process and trying to learn how redirection works. I am looking for suggestions w.r.t this tutorial. What I am doing wrong? Are there alternative methods to achieve the same result as this tutorial?
Thank you.

Comment: if you try redirect (replace) `wsock32.dll` to own - you must full implement it functional. export all, what original `wsock32.dll` export, but not only single function. you obvious not do this. as result network initialization and fail.

Comment: and at all `wsock32.dll` is obsolete now, almost not used. and `gethostbyname` it now not export

Comment: i look for [`wsock32.cpp`](http://sourcesecure.net/Articles/Code/wsock32.cpp) - of course all like this `#pragma comment (linker, "/export:AcceptEx=wsock32_.AcceptEx,@1141")` is invalid - now `mswsock.dll` export this but not `wsock32.dll` look like this code writed even for win2000 or early. because begin how minimum from xp - all this not valid